# How can I scroll a ScrolledComposited in Eclipse SWT Design view?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, design-view, scrolledcomposite

I have a Composite that is nested in a ScrolledComposite.  The ScrolledComposite works fine when running but I am wanting to find a way to be able to edit content in the Design view that falls beneath the ScrolledComposite height.  As of now I have to re-size my entire window (drag it down to view the components), edit the content, then size the window back.  I don't want to have to do this each time though.  Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. What is possible is to set the size of the gui outside the Class u are editing.
In my case i have a GUI class with shell.setSize(500,500) and compositie classes who have a bigger size setSize(1000,1000).